# button with text and outside of border's image

Tags: android, image, button

I want to create a `Button` that a piece of it's icon go outside of it,like this:

[image]

But, with this xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="40sp" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"  />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_btn"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
            android:text="delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_btn"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="share" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/like_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_btn"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:text="like" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I get some thing like this:

[image]

Is it possible image of `Button` ,goes over the border?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

delete_btn.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#F2F2F2" /> 
  <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="1dp" 
    android:right="7dp" android:bottom="1dp" /> 
  <corners android:radius="34dp" /> 
  <solid android:color="#F2F2F2"/> 
</shape>
```

Comment: You can set width and hight in the above code and try it

Comment: create image with transperent top, and put it on your button

Answer (score 0):

You can have to design your layout somewhat like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"  />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:background="@drawable/delete_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
        android:text="delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="share" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/like_btn"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:text="like" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks,can you give me an example?

Comment: if you could just upload the drawable resources files i can actually send you the proper code which you need to implement.

Comment: I put it to the first post

Comment: Please implement this code and see if you are getting the type of view you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35251/discussion-between-arshad-parwez-and-odr-m9611)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can **customize** `your way`.